# print a calenderwidget value to a textbox of another class onclick in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to print the date into the textbox when i click a date on the calendar. I am having trouble trying to pass the value to the textbox of the **Sentry** class from the **calendar** class. When I click on the date of the calendar the program does nothing. How can i pass the date from the calendar to the textbox.

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
 import sys

 class Sentry(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
    super(Sentry,self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(500,200, 600, 550)
    self.setWindowTitle("Student Entry")
    self.setupUi()
    
   def setupUi(self):
    self.dob = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.dob.setGeometry(320,60,70,60)
    self.dob.setText("DoB")
   
    self.dobbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
    self.dobbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380,70,170,30))


    self.cal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.cal.setGeometry(380,110,170,30)
    self.cal.setText("Show Calendar")
    self.cal.clicked.connect(self.show_calendar)
    

   def show_calendar(self):
    self.window = calendar()
    self.window.show()

    
 class calendar(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
    super(calendar,self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(500,200, 400, 400)
    self.main = Sentry()
    self.setupUi()
    

   def setupUi(self):
    self.calendars= QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
    self.calendars.setGeometry(0,0,400,400)
    self.calendars.clicked.connect(self.print_dob)

   def print_dob(self, qDate):
    date = ('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.year(),qDate.month(),qDate.day()))
    self.main.dobbox.setText(date)  

 if __name__=='__main__':
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = Sentry()
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please be more careful with your indentation. While you can obviously use any indentation style you want for your own code, on global communities it's always better to use standard conventions: indentation levels are 4 spaces. Also, read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), as your example also has spaces for the main indentation level, which results in syntax errors and makes it annoying to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Sentry` in the new calendar window, which doesn't make a lot of sense since one already exists and *that* instance is the one you want to access.

You either add the main instance as an argument for the new `calendar` instance and store it as `self.main`, or you connect its calendar widget clicked signal from the main instance.

Pass the main instance:

```py
class Sentry(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def show_calendar(self):
        self.window = calendar(self)
        self.window.show()


class calendar(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super(calendar,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,200, 400, 400)
        self.main = main
        self.setupUi()
```

Directly connect to the signal:

```
class Sentry(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def show_calendar(self):
        self.window = calendar()
        self.window.calendars.clicked.connect(self.print_dob)
        self.window.show()

    def print_dob(self, qDate):
        date = ('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.year(),qDate.month(),qDate.day()))
        print(date)
        self.dobbox.setText(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

    
class Calendar(QMainWindow):                                                 # Calendar
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                         # + parent
        super(Calendar, self).__init__(parent)                               # + parent
        self.parent = parent                                                 # +++
        
        self.setGeometry(500,200, 400, 400)
#        self.main = Sentry()                                                 # ---
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.calendars= QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.calendars.setGeometry(0,0,400,400)
        self.calendars.clicked.connect(self.print_dob)

    def print_dob(self, qDate):
        date = ('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.year(),qDate.month(),qDate.day()))
#        self.main.dobbox.setText(date)                                        # --
        self.parent.dobbox.setText(date)                                       # +++ self.parent.dobbox


class Sentry(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sentry,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,200, 600, 550)
        self.setWindowTitle("Student Entry")
        self.setupUi()
    
    def setupUi(self):
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.dob.setGeometry(320,60,70,60)
        self.dob.setText("DoB")
       
        self.dobbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.dobbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380,70,170,30))

        self.cal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.cal.setGeometry(380,110,170,30)
        self.cal.setText("Show Calendar")
        self.cal.clicked.connect(self.show_calendar)

    def show_calendar(self):
        self.window = Calendar(self)                                       # Calendar
        self.window.show()
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Sentry()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a variable to your `calendar()` class when you are calling it

Comment: I am still having the same problem